# Unable to link sourceMap in UglifyJS2

Tags: node.js, uglifyjs, source-maps

I am using following command in nodeJS script to generate sourceMap:

```
var uglifyRes = uglify.minify(jsFiles, {
    outSourceMap: path + ".js.map"
});

fs.writeFileSync('foo.js', uglifyRes.code);
fs.writeFileSync('foo.js.map', uglifyRes.map);
```

This code creates the map but the minified file doesn't have the reference to map. What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an opened issue for this case on git:

https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/135